# Scroll on clicking next and back button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, button, scroll, scrollview

I have a small problem associated with scrolling in android. Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<VideoView 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/video"
    />

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/channelview" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/backbtn"
        />

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backbtn"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nextbtn"
        android:id="@+id/scroll" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageholder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/next"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/nextbtn"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is I am adding Imageviews dynamically(more than 50 odd) to the linear layout and I am unsure of how to make it scroll by clicking the next and previous buttons that have been added on either side of the horizontal scrollview. By default if i swipe across the scrollview it does scroll, but i want to scroll either ways by means of clicking buttons too. Can anyone suggest me as to how to get it done with a sample code . Thanks.

Comment: hi i know this question is quite old. But am i also looking for the same functionality. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This way the scrollview can be scrolled to up or down.

```
scrollview.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // to scroll down
        scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        // to scroll up
        scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
    }
});
```

Comment: This will make it go to extreme top or extreme bottom of the view. I just want it to advance by a few amount.